# MVC 3 Generate - dash properties for JSON

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-3.0

I need to generate a JSON object as below using ASP.NET MVC 3.0 or above. All good except that some of the properties have - 'dash' e.g. scale-x. C# doesn't like this,
is there a way to workaround this?

```
{
    "Data" : [
        {
            "scale-x":{
                "values":["1","2"],
            },
            "scale-y":{
                "line-width":"1px",
                }
            },
            "series" : [
                {
                    "values" : [2, 5]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScriptSerializer - how to deserialize a property with a dash ("-") in it's name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494280/javascriptserializer-how-to-deserialize-a-property-with-a-dash-in-its-n)

Answer (score 0):

Use this as attribute for properties:

```
[DataMember(Name = "scale-x")]
```

Also you must use serializer in System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.
Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020889/asp-net-mvc-3-controller-json-method-serialization-doesnt-look-at-datamember-n).

Comment: System.Runtime.Serialization.Json doesn't seem to have Datamember attribute

Comment: DataMember in System.Runtime.Serialization namespace. And DataContractJsonSerializer in System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous types cannot have attributes used on them, your best bet is to just define a Proxy object as your own type and use it with the serializer, then use the above answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ClaySharp](http://clay.codeplex.com/)
A good example [by Hanselman is here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek6DynamicMalleableEnjoyableExpandoObjectsWithClay.aspx)

```
var person = New.Person();
person["FirstName"] = "Louis";
person["LastName"] = "Dejardin";
```