# How do I override a name in JSON returned by ASP.NET

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, datamember

I have the following code in an ASP.NET Web API 2 app:

```
[DataMember(Name = "override")]
public bool? _override;
```

But the JSON I receive has that member named _override, not override. How can I change the naming in the JSON?

Comment: Would this help?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686817/serialize-net-object-to-json-controlled-using-xml-attributes

Comment: I don't understand, you're receiving this JSON from somewhere and inside the JSON it has a name you want to change? The answer then is talk to whoever is sending you the JSON and ask them to change it.

Comment: My ASP.NET Web API server app has the above declaration. ASP.NET creates the JSON from a call where I pass back the object that includes the above member and ASP.NET JSONifies the object based on the object names.

Comment: `[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "override")]` attribute should do it

Comment: @shakib - that was it! If you write that as an answer I'm happy to mark it as the solution. thanks - dave

Comment: @DavidThielen added as answer. cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As asp.Net web API 2 uses `Json.NET` internally for json serialization/deserialization,

`JsonProperty` attribute can be used to override property name on serialization.

so `[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "override")]` should do the trick.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the name you want to output?
`public bool? @override;`

You can also use the `DataMember(Name="override)` attribute on your method, and `DataContract` attribute on your class, and then use the `DataContractJsonSerializer` class to serialize it as well.

See this post for a complete example on how to use DataContractJsonSerializer: [JavaScriptSerializer - how to deserialize a property with a dash ("-") in it's name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494280/javascriptserializer-how-to-deserialize-a-property-with-a-dash-in-its-n)